# jQuery - click on parent is inherited from children

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, parent-child

my situation is:

```
<div class="overlay">
<div class="modal"></div>
</div>
```

now i want that clicking overlay it hides both `.overlay` and `.modal` divs, so:

```
$('.overlay').on('click',function(){
$(this+',.modal').hide();
});
```

and it works, but there is a problem, if i click on `.modal` it does the same, and i don't want, **i need to tell to jquery to hide the divs only if i click on .overlay and not if i click on .modal**

How can i do? It seems the event attached to .overlay is inherited from childrens.

thanks in advice

Here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: use div id and trigger from id

Comment: @SJnawali really ? can you exaplain why please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Demo plz: http://jsfiddle.net/bcGZ3/3/

API:

- `.stopPropagation` - http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/
- `.preventDefault` http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

All you want is to stop popogation of the click even to the child div and Jquery apis abpve will help you do achieve that. BTW your jsfiddle sample is empty.

Hope it fits the need, `:)`

**Sample Code**

```
$('.overlay').on('click',function(){
        $(this).hide();
     alert("Parent div click function called.");
});


$(".modal").click(function(e) {
    // click on this link will cause ONLY child alert to fire
    e.stopPropagation();
    // stop default action of link
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Well-behaved child link click ONLY.\n\nAnd, Enjoy.");
});
```

Comment: i'll accept in 3 minutes, this fixed at all, really thanks dude!

Comment: @okok No worries bruv `:)` Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.overlay').on('click',function(evt){
    if(!$(evt.currentTarget).is('.modal')){
        $('.overlay, .modal').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: and `$('.overlay')` isn't doing the same as `$('.overlay:not(.modal)')` in his HTML example?

Comment: thanks, the first example won't work, the second returns **evt is not defined** error :(

Comment: That's weird...it should be the actual click event.

Comment: hey your solution is great anyway, but i need what the Tats_innit sad in his answer, that fixed at all, i tryed your solutions and they were the same i was trying by myself without results :(. So really really thanks anyway ;)